# C: using realloc for high performance with an array of structs

Tags: c, dynamic, structure, realloc

I am using realloc to adjust the size of an array of structs containing 3 points x, y and z.  This struct is encapsulated inside another struct that contains the array, the length of the array and a "reserved" value that is used for a pre-allocation strategy for even faster performance when it is evident that more structs of points will be appended to the struct array.
I am compiling with a Makefile that looks like this:

```
CFLAGS = -g -Wall
LIBS = -lm

default: echo "You must specify a target, e.g. file1, file2" 


file2:
    gcc $(CFLAGS) -o $@ test.c file2.c $(LIBS)
```

I have a function to initialize an empty array structure, one to reset the array to be empty and free any dynamically allocated memory, one to append a point to the end of the array and one to remove a point designated by the index value.

I am getting two errors that I cannot find the cause of.  One is that my code returns a non-zero status code of 1 and the other is the length seems to be off by one when I append a few thousand points.
I am letting the append function do all the work but if I should be allocating dynamic memory in initialization, please tell me so.  I am pretty sure that my reset and remove functions are working as they are supposed to.  Please take a look at append as well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct point
{
  int x, y, z;
} point_t;

typedef struct 
{
  // number of points in the array
  size_t len;

  // pointer to an array of point_t structs

  point_t* points;


  size_t reserved; 

} point_array_t;


void point_array_initial( point_array_t* pa )
{
    assert(pa);
    pa->len = 0;
    pa->reserved = 0;
    pa->points=NULL;
}   


void point_array_reset( point_array_t* pa )
{//just free the array and set pa to NULL

    assert(pa);

    pa->points = memset(pa->points, 0, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));
    pa->len = 0;
    pa->reserved=0;
    free(pa->points);
    pa->points=NULL;
}


int point_array_append( point_array_t* pa, point_t* p )
{

    assert(pa);
    assert(p);
    if(pa == NULL)//something wrong with intialization or reset
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if(p == NULL)//nothing to append
    {
        return 1;
    }
    //append the first point 
    if(pa->len == 0)
    {
        pa->len=1;
        pa->reserved=pa->len*2;
        pa->points = malloc(sizeof(point_t)* (pa->reserved));
        if(pa->points == NULL)//malloc failed
        {
            return 1;
        }

        pa->points[pa->len-1].x = p->x;
        pa->points[pa->len-1].y = p->y;
        pa->points[pa->len-1].z = p->z;
    }

    if (pa->reserved > pa->len )
    {
        pa->len+=1;
        pa->points[pa->len-1].x = p->x;//insert at index 0
        pa->points[pa->len-1].y = p->y;
        pa->points[pa->len-1].z = p->z;

    }
    //when we run out of space in reserved (len has caught up)
    else if(pa->reserved == pa->len)
    {
        pa->len+=1;
        pa->reserved=pa->len*2;
        pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->reserved));//doubling size of array
        pa->points[pa->len-1].x = p->x;//TODO: change formula to find insertion point
        pa->points[pa->len-1].y = p->y;
        pa->points[pa->len-1].z = p->z;
    }



    return 0;
}


int point_array_remove( point_array_t* pa, unsigned int i )
{

    assert(pa);
    if (i >= pa->len)//out of bounds
    {
        return 1;
    }   

    if(pa->len==0)//0 elements trying to remove from empty array
    {
        //pa->len=0;
        //free(pa->points);
        //pa->points=NULL; 
        return 1;
    }
    else if(pa->len ==1)//remove only element
    {
        pa->len-=1;//no copying required, just shorten
        pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));
        //free(pa->points);
        //pa->points=NULL;
    }
    else//array size is longer than 1 or 0
    {
        pa->points[i].x = pa->points[pa->len-1].x;
        pa->points[i].y = pa->points[pa->len-1].y;
        pa->points[i].z = pa->points[pa->len-1].z;  
        pa->len-= 1;//shorten array size
        pa->reserved = pa->len*2;
        pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));//could reallocate for reserve here to increase speed.
    }   

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just code `memset(pa->points, 0, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));` without assigning the (useless) result of `memset`

Comment: Then compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **use the debugger** `gdb`

Comment: As far as I can see, that `memset` line in your reset function is pointless. Get rid of it. And the math could definitely be simpler than you're making it in various other parts of the code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Well noted.  I will give the debugger a try although it is a bit intimidating.

Comment: `if (pa->reserved > pa->len )` --> `else if (pa->reserved > pa->len )`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, thanks again, I was thinking about doing that but assumed my `if(pa->len == 0)` code would be treated as case code and bypassed after the first point was appended.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Or just remove the entire special case by moving up and slightly editing the `pa->reserved == pa->len` case.

Comment: *The debugger is intimidating . . .* so get the feel for it with some simple code that you know is good, and you can introduce deliberate errors. Never try to solve two problems at once.

Comment: The first append "falls through" (i.e. the first `if` needs a `return`) and it gets appended twice. Or, at best, the append func can be simplified to a simple `if` that preceeds the fill of the array element.

Comment: `pa->len-=1;//no copying required, just shorten
        pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));` : Need change `pa->reserved`.

Comment: @CraigEstey, I am not 100% clear on the meaning of "falls through" but added a `return 0;` to the end of that case code.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, Well noted.  I can see how that would reduce the number of times realloc is called.

Comment: @WeatherVane, Well noted, I never thought of that.

Comment: That was it. "falls through" is because the first `if` continues rather than returning [double appending the first element]. Another way to do this is with an `else` ala chrqlie below

Comment: `pa->reserved = pa->len*2;
        pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));` : The actual reserved size is different from `pa->reserved`. In such a case `point_array_append` can not be executed normally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an `else` is missing after the `if(pa->len == 0)` body in the append function: the first point is appended twice.

Note that you have too many special cases in this function. It can be simplified into just a one test: if the array is too small, reallocate it, and append the point.

Other simplifications are possible:

- the test `if (pa->len == 0)//0 elements trying to remove from empty array` is redundant with the previous one.
- take advantage of the fact that `realloc(NULL, size)` is equivalent to `malloc(size)` and `realloc(p, 0)` to `free(p)`, and `free(NULL)` is OK.
- beware that `realloc()` may fail, even when shrinking the block.
- you should only shrink the array when it becomes too sparse, not for every call to `point_array_remove`.

Here is a simpler version:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct point {
    int x, y, z;
} point_t;

typedef struct {
    size_t len;      // number of valid points in the array
    size_t reserved; // allocated number of points in the array
    point_t *points; // pointer to an array of point_t structs
} point_array_t;

void point_array_initial(point_array_t *pa) {
    assert(pa);
    pa->len = 0;
    pa->reserved = 0;
    pa->points = NULL;
}

void point_array_reset(point_array_t *pa) {
    assert(pa);
    free(pa->points);
    pa->len = 0;
    pa->reserved = 0;
    pa->points = NULL;
}

int point_array_append(point_array_t *pa, const point_t *p) {
    point_t *points;

    assert(pa);
    assert(p);
    // no need to test pa nor p, asserts would already abort
    points = pa->points;
    if (pa->len >= pa->reserved || points == NULL) {
        // reallocate of points array is too small
        size_t newsize = pa->reserved;
        if (newsize < pa->len)
            newsize = pa->len;
        if (newsize < 1)
            newsize = 1;
        newsize += newsize;
        points = realloc(points, newsize * sizeof(*points);
        if (points == NULL)
            return 1;
        pa->points = points;
        pa->reserved = newsize;
    }
    // append point structure
    points[pa->len++] = *p;
    return 0;
}

int point_array_remove(point_array_t *pa, unsigned int i) {
    point_t *points;

    assert(pa);
    if (i >= pa->len || pa->points == NULL) { //out of bounds or invalid array
        return 1;
    }
    if (pa->len - i > 1) {
        memmove(&pa->points + i, &pa->points + i + 1,
                sizeof(*pa->points) * (pa->len - i - 1));
    }
    pa->len--;
    if (pa->reserved >= pa->len * 3) {
        size_t newsize = pa->len * 2;
        // shorten the array with care.
        // note that the array will be freed when it becomes empty
        // no special case needed.
        points = realloc(pa->points, sizeof(*points) * newsize);
        if (points != NULL) {
            pa->points = points;
            pa->reserved = newsize;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think I understand how to fix it but need to look again to see why it is appended twice.  So all the other code should fall under the `else`.

Comment: Yes, you test `if(pa->len == 0)` then add a point and then test `if (pa->reserved > pa->len )` after adding `1` to `len` and setting `reserved`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, yes, I regret now using test code that was provided to me by someone else.

Comment: @chqrlie, Please give me some time to review your solution code.  I am still trying to get the hang of dereferencing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error pointed out by chqrlie, here are a few additional thoughts on your code.

A better choice of CFLAGS for non-debug builds would be

```
-Wall -Wextra -O3
```

add `-pedantic` for a few additional warnings and you can use `-Ofast` with gcc >= 4.6.

Never `realloc` the pointer itself, If `realloc` fails, `NULL` is returned and you have lost the reference to your original memory block -- and created a memory leak because you no longer have the beginning address of the block to `free`. Don't increment `len` or `reserved` until you validate `realloc` succeeded. Instead, always use a temporary pointer and increment values only on success, e.g.

```
else if(pa->reserved == pa->len)
{
    void *tmp = realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len + 1) * 2);
    if (!tmp) {
        /* handle error - exit or return */
    }
    pa->points = tmp;
    pa->len+=1;
    pa->reserved=pa->len*2;
}
```

The following looks like a problem if you are simply wanting to shorten the array by one:

```
else if(pa->len ==1)//remove only element
{
    pa->len-=1;//no copying required, just shorten
    pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));
    //free(pa->points);
    //pa->points=NULL;
}
else//array size is longer than 1 or 0
{
    pa->points[i].x = pa->points[pa->len-1].x;
    pa->points[i].y = pa->points[pa->len-1].y;
    pa->points[i].z = pa->points[pa->len-1].z;  
    pa->len-= 1;//shorten array size
    pa->reserved = pa->len*2;
    pa->points=realloc(pa->points, sizeof(point_t)*(pa->len));//could reallocate for reserve here to increase speed.
}
```

In the `else` above you are assigning the previous point to the last, then chopping off the last -- either I don't understand what you are trying to accomplish, or it's not doing what you think it is. In either case, unless you have some compelling reason for wanting to `realloc` to shorten the array by one (I'd wait until all add/remove operations are done and then call a final realloc on `len` element to exactly size your memory use). Instead, I would replace the entirety of the above with:

```
else
    pa->len -= 1;
```

No need to mess with anything else. You effectively ignore the data in the last row -- which isn't hurting anything, until your next add overwrites the values.

Comment: I apologize for not specifying the requirement earlier but the `int i` parameter in remove designates the index to be removed and the requirements are for an unstable remove that may change the ordering of the array.  Hence, I copied the last index element to the index to be removed and then shortened the length.

Comment: That's what was unclear. The copy of one element if you are removing one in the middle would necessitate copying in sequence `i+1` to `i` until `len` is reached. No need to apologize, it was just a bit confusing. I see what you are doing now -- just saving the point you are removing in the one you want to delete.

Comment: I will definitely change the ordering as suggested regarding the realloc position and memory leaks.

Comment: @NickAnoyot given those requirements (which I *think* are clearer), then as I mentioned in general-comment, the math can be simplified significantly. [see it live](http://ideone.com/dKf8GP). It at-least-seems that's all you're trying to do, but I caution you, compressing and/or expanding can easily "butterfly" if you find yourself sitting at, or near, an expansion/compression point and then perform a ton of fairly balanced insertions and removals. Anyway, best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig - as always, fantastic example that would be instrumental posted as an answer.